# Is there a way to treat special characters in users input variable as literal?

Tags: awk

Learning more about awk however I cannot figure out a way to treat a special character as literal in the awk ~ pattern for example I have a txt file which contains

```
C++ for dummies:test1:test2
java for dummies:test1:test2
bash for dummies:test1:test2
```

say I would like user to be able to search for a matching pattern based on the first field e.g user types in dummies the output will be

```
C++ for dummies:test1:test2
java for dummies:test1:test2
bash for dummies:test1:test2
```

or if user types the whole string C++ for dummies the output will be

```
C++ for dummies:test1:test2
```

the actual output comes out blank as it contains special character

but just typing C++ alone yields the output

```
C++ for dummies:test1:test2
```

A blackslash would help however this is by a user input meaning I would have no idea what the input would be like.

this is what i have coded

```
read titleInput
awk -v title="$titleInput" -F: '$1~title {print $0}' textF.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `~` for a regular expression match, use the `index` function which considers it's search argument as a plain string and not an RE:

```
$ echo 'C++ for dummies:test1:test2' | awk  -F: -v title="C++ for dummies" 'index($1, title)'
C++ for dummies:test1:test2
```

Comment: is it possible to use a print{} for index? as I would like to modify the output C++ for dummies,$test1,test2

Comment: Yes, I only left it out because `{print $0}`. Is the default action.  You can add it back and modify it as you wish.